# What does a returned link to a C ++ object look like

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

1) I do not understand what * this looks like

2) I don’t understand what the return link to the object looks like

3) When this link is returned, what happens in the part c = a = b

```
 MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& copyObject) {
        //Copy dynamic array
        return *this 
    }

    int main(){
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(3)
    MyClass c(3)
    c=a=b;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returned link"?

Comment: @eerorika that's bad translation, link, reference and connection sa,e single word in original

Comment: @eerorika after a = b i should get reference at object.But i  don't understand what that means and how that reference looks like.And what is going on with that reference after i will get it

Comment: @ZELIBOBA it means it doesn't copy it. reference is like poinrer which doesn't requre dereference and cannot be changed. You have take book and read about refernces. refernce can be used to modify object if it's not Constant reference. function takes constant reference, so it can take non-constant one too. Unless something happens before `return`, that line yields no operation

Answer (score 3):

It's not link, it's a reference (russian ссылка is a translator's enemy word). `this` is pointer to instance, your operator return a reference to current object operator was called for. Dereferencing a pointer returns a reference.

That line equals to due operator associativity

```
c=(a=b)
```

Or

```
c.operator=(a.operator=(b))
```

Nothing happens because your operator doesn't do anything to object

Comment: I don't understand why while i'm dereferencing a pointer  i will take a reference. This is a pointer witch contains the address of my object witch called method (that is b).I thought that i would get the object not his reference. However where this address will be written?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA reference is an alias of object. Unless refernce is member of class or a variable with static class of storage, it doesn't have representation. When passed to or returned from function, it returned as address to object but it's not same as pointer!

Comment: As i understand it is my reference MyClass &ref=a; After that a = ref; Then c = a;  MyClass &ref2=c; then c=ref2 . But when a= ref or c = ref2 , am i calling the operator = witch i have reloaded? Something like that a.operator=(ref) ?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Yes, that's essence of references. If you take value of expression `&ref`, you'll get a pointer to `a`. For a free-standing `operator=` there are two parameters, first of which should be non-const reference (i.e. argument should be so called lvalue expression, one on left side of =), for member one  first argument is object for which operator was called (i.e.`*this`). So canonical member `operator=` should copy values from its argument referred by `copyObject` to current object, then return a reference to `*this` to allow chaining. Returning value would create excess copies of object